# what is the benefit of lcm in cryptography?

Tags: public-key

what is the benefit of lcm in cryptography?
and what is the effect of lcm on public key?

note *
lcm = Least common multiple

thanks

Comment: Lcm or least common multiple is simply a concept in math, it does not have a special meaning (or benefit) in cryptography. The least common multiple of two numbers $x$ and $y$ is simply the smallest number $z$ so that both $x$ and $y$ divide $z$. For example $lcm(9, 30) = 90$ because $90 = 9\cdot10$ and $90 = 3\cdot30$ and there is no smaller number that both $9$ and $30$ divides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding public key: In two prime RSA you often compute the secret key from the public as $d=e^{-1} \pmod {(p-1)(q-1)},\;$ but using $d=e^{-1} \pmod {\mathrm{lcm}(p-1,q-1)}$ may have some advantages.

Comment: Note that it has fewer advantages than you'd hope: if you use the CRT optimization (which most people do), then both $e^{-1} \pmod {(p-1)(q-1)}$ and $e^{-1} \pmod {\mathrm{lcm}(p-1,q-1)}$ lead to the same value of $dp$ and $dq$, and so they operate exactly the same.

Comment: Saying "may have some advantages" does not explain what those advantages actually are.